# API to get hostname from Jscript

Tags: javascript

I am not sure why my previous post was not listed. Lets see if this one gets listed.
I have a stand alone jScript which passes parameters to a C# program. I have to pass hostname to the C# program. Is there an api which I can use to get hostname in the jScript if not can I do it using the 'hostname' system command?

Thanks in Advance.
Sam

Answer (score 5):

Since you're using JScript I assume you're running under Windows. You can get the current computer's name from the environment:

```
var env, computerName;
env = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell").Environment("Process");
computerName = env("COMPUTERNAME");
```

...if that's what you mean by hostname. More on environments (there are  more than one available, above I picked the process's environment) [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fd7hxfdd(v=VS.85).aspx).

Comment: This is pretty much I wanted. Keeping rocking!

/Sam

Comment: When I run multiple of these scrips. This is creating lots of WScript.exe*32 process on the system. Should I do delete env after getting ComputerName? 

Thanks in advance,
Sam

Comment: @Sam: No, you can't delete a `var`. You may want to add `env = undefined;` after you're done using it, to explicitly break the reference to it. Blast Microsoft and their reference counting issues! ;-)

Comment: What a nightmare ActiveX was 

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler - Big time. :-)