# Angular 14 : How to get the System's Hostname ; not the domain name

Tags: angular, hostname, angular14

On the internet, many suggest using window.location.hostname

But this code gives the domain name

What I'm interested is the system's hostname(In the command prompt, run hostname)

Is it possible to get the **System's hostname** in Angular 14?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible.

There is no JS API to access the system hostname, that would be a privacy nightmare.

Edit: Actually [there was a way on Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397068/api-to-get-hostname-from-jscript) with ActiveX.